# Как правильно подсчитать совпадающие элементы в двух списках?

Tags: python, list

У меня есть два списка

```
list_1 = [['появление', 'NOUN'], ['ООН', 'PROPN'], ['было', 'AUX'], ['обусловлено', 'VERB'], ['целым', 'ADJ'], ['рядом', 'NOUN'], ['объективных', 'ADJ'], ['факторов', 'NOUN'], ['военно', 'ADJ'], ['стратегического', 'ADJ'], ['политического', 'ADJ'], ['экономического', 'ADJ'], ['развития', 'NOUN'], ['человеческого', 'ADJ'], ['общества', 'NOUN'], ['конца', 'NOUN'], ['второго', 'NUM'], ['тысячелетия', 'NOUN'], ['создание', 'NOUN'], ['ООН', 'NOUN'], ['явилось', 'VERB'], ['воплощением', 'NOUN'], ['извечной', 'ADJ'], ['мечты', 'NOUN'], ['человечества', 'NOUN'], ['о', 'ADP'], ['таком', 'PRON'], ['устройстве', 'NOUN'], ['и', 'CCONJ'], ['организации', 'NOUN'], ['международного', 'ADJ'], ['общежития', 'NOUN'], ['которые', 'PRON'], ['избавили', 'VERB'], ['бы', 'x'], ['человечество', 'NOUN'], ['от', 'ADP'], ['бесконечности', 'NOUN'], ['череды', 'NOUN'], ['войн', 'NOUN'], ['и', 'CCONJ'], ['обеспечили', 'VERB'], ['бы', 'x'], ['мирные', 'ADJ'], ['условия', 'NOUN'], ['жизни', 'NOUN'], ['народов', 'NOUN'], ['их', 'PRON'], ['поступательное', 'ADJ']]
list_2 = [['появление', 'NOUN'], ['ООН', 'NOUN'], ['было', 'VERB'], ['обусловлено', 'VERB'], ['целым', 'ADJ'], ['рядом', 'NOUN'], ['объективных', 'ADJ'], ['факторов', 'NOUN'], ['военно', 'ADJ'], ['стратегического', 'ADJ'], ['политического', 'ADJ'], ['экономического', 'ADJ'], ['развития', 'NOUN'], ['человеческого', 'ADJ'], ['общества', 'NOUN'], ['конца', 'NOUN'], ['второго', 'NUM'], ['тысячелетия', 'NOUN'], ['создание', 'NOUN'], ['ООН', 'PROPN'], ['явилось', 'VERB'], ['воплощением', 'NOUN'], ['извечной', 'ADJ'], ['мечты', 'NOUN'], ['человечества', 'NOUN'], ['о', 'ADP'], ['таком', 'DET'], ['устройстве', 'NOUN'], ['и', 'CCONJ'], ['организации', 'NOUN'], ['международного', 'ADJ'], ['общежития', 'NOUN'], ['которые', 'PRON'], ['избавили', 'VERB'], ['бы', 'x'], ['человечество', 'NOUN'], ['от', 'ADP'], ['бесконечности', 'NOUN'], ['череды', 'NOUN'], ['войн', 'NOUN'], ['и', 'CCONJ'], ['обеспечили', 'VERB'], ['бы', 'x'], ['мирные', 'ADJ'], ['условия', 'NOUN'], ['жизни', 'NOUN'], ['народов', 'NOUN'], ['их', 'PRON'], ['поступательное', 'ADJ']]
```

Я хочу сравнить два списка и подсчитать сколько элементов совпадает.
мой код:

```
result22 = []
for c in list_1:
    for x in list_2:
        if c == x:
            result22.append(c)
        else:
            break
print(len(result22))
```

У меня выходит ответ 1, но должно получиться около 45. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас если первый элемент второго списка не равен текущему элементу первого списка, то дальнейшее сравнение не производится. Нужно убрать  `else`.

```
if c == x:
    result22.append(c)
    break
```

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Нужно убрать только `esle:`, тк поиск должен прекращаться. То есть, `break` поставить после `result22.append(c)`.

Comment: @MichaelTetelev да, верно

Comment: @MichaelTetelev Он мне выдает 47, т.е он почему-то считает список ['ООН', 'PROPN']. И так происходит дважды

Comment: @Эникейщик Он мне выдает 47, т.е он почему-то считает список ['ООН', 'PROPN']. И так происходит дважды

Comment: @irina2020 а почему не должен? Есть в обоих списках, потому и считает

Comment: @Эникейщик в первом списке ['ООН', 'PROPN'], а во втором ['ООН', 'NOUN']. Они должны совпадать по двум элементам.

Comment: @irina2020 Ну так ООН PROPN во втором дальше тоже есть

Comment: @irina2020 если нужно сравнить поэлементно, то `len(list(a == b for (a, b) in zip(list_1, list_2)))` сделает то, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в условии `else`, которое вызывает оператор `break`. В таком случае при первом же неравенстве двух элементов вы просто выходите из списка. Что бы всё работало вам просто надо убрать ветку `else`.

**Важно заметить!** В случае, если у вас есть несколько одинаковых элементов в списке они будут почитаны большее кол-во раз, чем они там упоминаются

Answer (score 0):

если установлен `pandas` то вот такое слегка громоздкое выражение вернет нужный результат:

```
import pandas as pd

print(pd.Series(map(' '.join,list_1)).isin(list(map(' '.join,list_2))).sum())  # 47
```

а если так, то повторы считаться не будут:

```
print(pd.Series(map(' '.join,list_1)).drop_duplicates()
     .isin(list(map(' '.join,list_2))).sum())  # 45
```

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка?

Ты сравниваешь элементы, а надо проверять вхождение элемента в список

```
sum(e in list_2 for e in list_1)
```